# How to get Call History in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Am I able to get the current call history with the call number and DateTime details from the phone with the API? I think it is not possible with the current one.

if possible then please help me.

Comment: any budy idea how to get call history in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 3):

It is **not** possible to get the call history as there is no public API to get that.

**On a side note:**

You can raise your concern at [How can we improve the Windows platform?](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform), if you want.

Comment: it is possible for android why not possible for windows phone?

Comment: @DenishParvadia:- I am not sure but the best I can say is Android is Google's monoppoly and windows is Microsoft. May be in future Microsoft can add or provide some API for it but at present it is not there.

Comment: @DenishParvadia:- As far as I know that Microsoft does not provide this facility due to some privacy concerns.

Comment: Imagine a malicious app that would read your entire call history and sell this data about you to 3rd party companies. I have noticed a lot of very popular apps have an incredibly long list of requirements for them to work.